# Reflecting C# types in F#

Tags: c#, reflection, f#

I've loaded a C# dll in a Fsi session. Running C# methods returns some C# types. I've written a helper function to explore the Properties for a given C# type.

The program is failing with an error:

```
stdin(95,21): error FS0039: The type 'RuntimePropertyInfo' is not defined
```

Is this possible to do? Or am I beating a dead horse?

```
let getPropertyNames (s : System.Type)=
    Seq.map (fun (t:System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo) -> t.Name) (typeof<s>.GetProperties())
```

`typeof<TypeName>.GetProperties() //seems to work.`

I'm just aiming for a pretty print of C# fields.

## Update

I think I've found a way to do this. And it seems to work. I'm not able to answer myself. So I'll accept the answer of anyone who gives a better example than this.

```
let getPropertyNames (s : System.Type)=
    let properties = s.GetProperties()
    properties 
        |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Name) 
        |> Array.iter (fun x -> printfn "%s" x)
```

Comment: `System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo` seems to be internal and sealed in .NET 4.0. Is there a reason you're trying to use it instead of `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`? I've never used the former, but maybe you've tried the latter and there's a reason you're not using it - which is why I'm wondering.

Comment: @Roujo I did a typeof on the the Properties themselves. This is the type I got. I should have probably checked myself. Anyway, I think I found a way to make this work without too much type annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo` in the type annotation. Your code also has `typeof<s>`, but `s` is already a variable of type `System.Type`, so you can just call `GetProperties` on `s` directly:

```
let getPropertyNames (s : System.Type)=
    Seq.map (fun (t:System.Reflection.PropertyInfo) -> t.Name) (s.GetProperties())

getPropertyNames (typeof<System.String>)
```

You can also avoid the type annotation altogether by using pipe:

```
let getPropertyNames (s : System.Type)=
    s.GetProperties() |> Seq.map (fun t -> t.Name)
```